# NestJS Monorepo Microservices Deployment to Heroku with Shared Files

Tags: heroku, microservices, nestjs, monorepo

Currently, I am building a monorepo microservices with an apigateway using Redis to communicate.  I am planning to deploy each services into different dynos in Heroku. Currently, it's pretty straightforward since every service has its own package.json, tsconfig.json, and Procfile. I could deploy them using `git subtree` The problem occurs when I want to have a shared files. For example I want to share the same DTOs across microservices to minimize bug and error. Does anyone have any idea on how to approach this?
Current File Structure:

```
Project
|    .git
|
|____Apigateway
|    |  Procfile
|    |  package.json
|
|____Microservice 1
|    |  Procfile
|    |  package.json
|
|____Microservice 2
|    |  Profile
|    |  package.json
```

Desired File Structure:

```
Project
|    .git
|    create.dto.ts
|    delete.dto.ts
|
|____Apigateway
|    |  Procfile
|    |  package.json
|
|____Microservice 1
|    |  Procfile
|    |  package.json
|
|____Microservice 2
|    |  Profile
|    |  package.json
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to do this is to create a [Nest.js library](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/libraries#libraries) and then add the library as a dependency to the individual services in their respective `package.json` files using a [local path](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#local-paths).